# Bootstrap grid same height and with

Tags: flask, bootstrap-4, version-control, grid

I'm creating a real estate with boostrap ccs and i'm trying organized my ads. However i can't find the way to make them all to the same size. i want for each line 3 ads. In this search  only found 5 ads.

the next image is what i have using:

div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-5"

[My situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXWCJ.png)

And what i'm looking for is:

[The future](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dzx7.png)

thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
     <!-- Add advert item here -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
     <!-- Add advert item here -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
     <!-- Add advert item here -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
     <!-- Add advert item here -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
     <!-- Add advert item here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Also you will need to adjust for media queries for smaller screens.

Comment: doesn't work as I need, Because sometimes i have mor than 3000 Ads.  I need another option

Comment: Could you add the code which renders this and update the question?